# Spring Boot 3 Test Service cannot find database table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I am creating a new Spring Boot 3.14 application for myself, and I found myself stuck, and I just need a little help in moving forward.   I have a previous Spring Boot 3.0.5 application which does not have this problem.

The main Spring Boot application is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JobSearchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobSearchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The DatabaseConfiguration class is as follows:

```
package com.tomholmes.product.jobsearch.config;
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.tomholmes.product.jobsearch")
@EntityScan("com.tomholmes.product.jobsearch.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.tomholmes.product.jobsearch.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
}
```

My Hibernate Entity works fine, my Hibernate Repository code works fine, and I have a simple test which shows that the database connection works fine.   Let me show you the simple test:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class RoleRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testFindById() {
        long id = 1;
        RoleEntity roleEntity = repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        assertNotNull(roleEntity);
        assertEquals(id, roleEntity.getId());
     }
}
```

Now it's time to implement the service code test which I have like this.  And you will notice I am using Constructor Injection as this has become the standard.

```
@Transactional
@Service("roleService")
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public RoleServiceImpl(RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public RoleEntity getById(long id) {
        RoleEntity role = roleRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        return role;
    }
}
```

Now comes the part where the Integration Test for this should be super-easy, and with my older project (Spring Boot 3.0.5) this worked, but with Spring Boot 3.1.4 something changed.   So, here is the test, and then I will tell you what error message is coming up.   So, first the test code as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = JobSearchApplication.class)
@Transactional
public class RoleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RoleService service;
    
    @Test
    public void testGetById() {
        long id = 1;
        RoleEntity entity = service.getById(id);
        assertNotNull(entity);
        assertEquals(id, entity.getId());
    }
}
```

Now the error that I get is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.role' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
... 156 common frames omitted
```

So, I completely do not understand why the test is looking is looking for a table 'test.role' instead of 'role'.   I've looked at older projects, and I've done some searching on Google for an answer to this, but I haven't seen any ideas on why this is happening.

I tried to change the test to include:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = JobSearchApplication.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class)
```

and that doesn't work.   I want to make it clear that I am using MySQL with the latest driver, and I want to use the real database for testing out my business logic.  So, any help with this would be big.  I am sure it might be something small.

If I need to provide anything else, please let me know, and I can add more info.
Thanks!

UPDATED: Providing the application.properties file as follows:

```
# Spring Boot - Hibernate6 settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/job_search_db?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: It appears it's looking for your table "role" in a schema or database named "test".
Did you cross-check your configuration files, especially if you have one for tests?

Comment: The fact that you have that `DatabaseConfiguration` makes we wonder. If your `JobSearchApplication` is in the `com.tomholmes.product.jobsearch` you don't need it (in fact it might even disable parts of the auto-configuration). Please add your `application.properties` to the question.

Comment: @M.Deinum The Database Configuration is absolutely in the right path/package.  Also, I have added the application.properties as requested.

Comment: Where do I state it isn't in the right package, you shouldn't need that class at all.

Comment: @M.Deinum then I misunderstood what you were saying.  I did remove the database configuration, and it removed the issue altogether.  But, I'd like to know what it was about my configuration that was causing the issue.

Comment: If your `@SpringBootApplication` class is in the top-level package (as recommended by the Spring Boot team/documentation) you don't need all those additional configurations (as a general rule of thumb). Adding them disabled (parts) of the auto configuration from Spring Boot. I suspect the combination of `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` but as stated you won't need it as it is provided out-of-the-box for you. Generally when you start doing things like this you need to get your hands from the keyboard, take 2 steps back and really think if you need it when using Spring Boot.